# Avoiding overlapping with fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a fixed navigation at the top of the webpage. But then the wrapper content would overlap. So I'm setting the margin-top with jQuery:

```js
$('#wrapper').css('margin-top', function() {return $('nav').height();});
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2.5;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    nav {
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
    NAV
</nav>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id="header" class="alt">
        HEADER
    </header>
    <main>
        Lorem <br>
        ipsum <br>
        dolor <br>
        sit <br>
        amet <br>
    </main>     
</div>
```

But then, if I open the page in a small window and then maximize it, the nav will resize but the `margin-top` will stay the same.

As I understand, the `css` function is called only once. Is it possible to bind `margin-top` of the `#wrapper` to the `height` of `nav`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it on document ready and on window resize. For instance:

```
function setWrapper() {
    $('#wrapper').css('margin-top', $('nav').height() );
};

$(setWrapper);
$(window).resize(setWrapper);
```

You may also want to throttle or debounce the call to the function.

An alternative would be to use "regular" css and media queries to set the margin-top.

Comment: But I only know `line-height`, not the pixel height for the nav, so I can't really use it in regular css, afaik. Besides, what if I use `$('nav').resize(...)` instead? This would be failsafe for any future navbar height changes, not connected with the window resizing. What does it mean to throttle or debounce?

Comment: Ah ok I thought you do know the height, but that it changes frequently with the window width (hence media queries). Anyway, then the jquery would be the way to go. I think resize event is trigger on window only, so you should use that.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the function and return

Answer (score 0):

Recall the settings on window resize:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
$('#wrapper').css('margin-top', function() {return $('nav').height();});
})
```

Comment: I need both the original `.css(...)` call and the `resize` handler, don't I?

Comment: Yes. I said **Recall** because you have to call once at `$(document).ready()` and also on `$(window).resize()`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to trigger the resize event in the start as well like following

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#wrapper').css('margin-top', $('nav').height());
}).trigger('resize');
```